# Installing ubuntu 16.04.1 on new ssd drive from live Usb , ErrNo5 during installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, dell, ssd

As said I am trying to install on my del inspiron 5521 laptop with the new (only one existing inside the system) SSD samsung evo 850.
I am receiving the following error during installation

> "The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:
>
> [Errno 5] Input/output error
>
> This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
>   disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
>   speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
>   available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
>   is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
>   environment."

I tried couple of proposed solutions like here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1910258

the

1. Boot from the live CD
2. Choose to try Ubuntu
3. Open a terminal window
4. Enter: ubiquity --no-migration-assistant
5. Working install

4 step command didnt exist in my system

> Usage: ubiquity [options] [frontend]
>
> ubiquity: error: no such option: --no-migration-assistant

I tried playing with BIOS UEFI/Legacy
and sata options ATA/ACHI parameters 
(all the four possible combinartion)

Logs of /var/log/installer/debug

```
Ubiquity 2.21.63.2
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py:53: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib, Atk
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:195: PyGIWarning: TimezoneMap was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('TimezoneMap', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import TimezoneMap
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
update_release_notes_label()
Could not translate page (prepare): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 319 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 478 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:98: PyGIWarning: Soup was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Soup', '2.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib, Soup
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py:72: Warning: Source ID 1832 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.keyboard_layout_timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py:74: Warning: Source ID 1834 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.keyboard_variant_timeout_id)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 1443 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 1595 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 3592 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 3834 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 4982 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 5101 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 5420 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 5548 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 5789 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 5942 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 6234 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 6379 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 6574 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 6745 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 6909 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 6952 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 6977 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 7097 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 7128 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 7243 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
update_release_notes_label()
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 7289 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 7409 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

Comment: Maybe a corrupted ISO or install medium? Have you tried to re-download and burn a new DVD/USB?

Comment: The liveUsb worked and have installed the same to install ubuntu in different laptop

Comment: If you already re-dowloaded and re-burned the installation medium, check if you BIOS version is up to date. If problem persists, maybe a faulty drive _(ssd or usb)_ is causing the I/O error.

Comment: I had previously debian in this laptop btw with the previous HDD. 
BIOS not updto date put windows distro to update

Comment: To install ubuntu on a blank disk this post may help : https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/171636